# Facebook comments box with comments from multiple urls

Tags: facebook, comments

I am looking at replacing the comments on my news site with a facebook comments box. This would mean that every time someone posts a news article people can comment on it. This would require many comment boxes for many urls.

On the front page of my site however, I have a feed to all the comments that are posted all over the page. This makes is useful for people to see the discussion happening around the site.

Is there a way to show all the comments that are being posted on my site in one location if I move to facebook comments?

Essentially it would be a feed of all the comments from the different urls.

Answer (score 0):

For each url you have, you would need to occasionaly pull the comments down using the [Facebook Graph Comments API](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/490) with a URL like: https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments.  You would then need to build something to display this. There are no social plugins built for this.